# Android how to use new features of 2.2 and still keep code compatible with 2.1 api

Tags: android

I would like to use push notification (available from 2.2 onwards) for my app. But I would also like to keep my app compatible for devices with 2.1 API. How do I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the method shown [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html).

Answer (score 0):

Keep two separate wrappers for both versions on your app then load the appropriate wrapper on app init based on the firmware version.